# Shamir's Secret Sharing doesn't work with large ints

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I am to use a Python example of Shamir's Secret Sharing from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).  When I give it number a larger than `170.141.183.460.469.231.731.687.303.715.884.105.726` it gives completely different output.

Why doesn't it work after that number and is there a way to get around this?

Comment: please provide your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is that all calculations are happening modulo `2 ** 127 - 1` which is `170,141,183,460,469,231,731,687,303,715,884,105,727`.

Replace the line:

```
_PRIME = 2 ** 127 - 1
```

with a larger prime to increase the limit.  They suggest

```
_PRIME = 2**521 - 1
```